# FuseEsb where are stored my classes

Tags: jar, fuseesb

i deployed through maven my jar in Fuse Esb .
Where fuse esb store my classes ? 
I've searched in my installation but nothing. 
I use fuse-esb-7.0.0.fuse-061 . 
Thanks !
Carlo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fuse ESB stores the JARs locally in its cache, which is located in data/cache. The local cache renames the JARs to something else, such as bundle146 etc.